# create iis application via java

Tags: java, .net, iis

We have build several web service based on .net.

Now we want to create a Uniform UI to manage these kinds of services based on web.

But we want to use java in this system,so we have to create/start/stop iis application in java.

I wonder if this is possible?

Comment: Curious to know if you have everything in .Net AND your problem can be  solved using .Net, why introduce java ?

Comment: Maybe Java is missing in their CVs. And now they see the chance to add that too. I think it's called *design by CV*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a command line tool for managing IIS web applications called [appcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Furthermore, there are *iisreset*, *net start* and *net stop*.

You can call these command line tools from Java using *Runtime.exec* or using the *ProcessBuilder* class. The most likely require elevated privileges. So your Java application will need to run with elevated privileges as well.

I'm not quite sure whether this is already sufficient for your management application. You don't mention anything about querying the web applications and their state. Wouldn't that be required as well?

Comment: OMG,I Forget it,Yes,we need to query tie Status of the service